# getting vertices in order from spanning tree

Tags: graphs-and-networks, trees

I've got spanning tree for some weighted graph (edges labeled 1-6) - for example:

```
graphMatrix = {{0, 0.140892, 0.298153, 1.13827, 1.27866, 1.4}, {0.140892, 0, 
0.167897, 1.16492, 1.3422, 1.49614}, {0.298153, 0.167897, 0, 
1.13035, 1.35045, 1.54743}, {1.13827, 1.16492, 1.13035, 0, 0.375184,
0.773562}, {1.27866, 1.3422, 1.35045, 0.375184, 0, 0.412249}, {1.4,
1.49614, 1.54743, 0.773562, 0.412249, 0}};

graph = Graph[WeightedAdjacencyGraph[graphMatrix], 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"];
tree = Graph[FindSpanningTree[graph], VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

How can I get vertices of tree in order in which they appear in this tree?

(In this case it should be `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`).

Edit: Second example, when given such tree:

[image: quite specific tree]

Result should be `{68, 2, 193, 88, 129, …}` or `{197, 198, …}`

Comment: For your graph, `VertexList[tree]` does the right thing...

Comment: VertexList[tree] will always return all vertices with normal ordering (1,2,3,…) - even if tree is something like (3 -> 1, 1 -> 2).

Comment: Notice that there is no canonical ordering on trees that I am aware of, so what would you expect?

Comment: @IgorRivin I've added some clarification.

Comment: Esse, `VertexList` returns all vertices in the order they are appear in the input to `Graph`. So, if you don't use an explicit vertex list as the first argument in `Graph` `VertexList` gives the vertices in the order they appear in the edge list you enter as the first argument of `Graph`. Try, for example,  `g= Graph[{3 -> 1, 1 -> 2}];  VertexList[g]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your graph is a path graph, only thing you need to do is finding root (starting vertex).  Once you find root, you could do [`DepthFirstScan`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DepthFirstScan.html) ([like Igor Rivin suggested](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60452/1356)), [`BreadthFirstScan`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BreadthFirstScan.html), [`VertexComponent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VertexComponent.html), etc...

For example:

```
g = PathGraph[RandomSample[Range[100], 100], VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
roots = VertexList[g][[Flatten[Position[VertexDegree[g], 1]]]]
```

> {21, 83}

```
r1 = Reap[DepthFirstScan[g, roots[[1]], {"PrevisitVertex" -> Sow}]][[2, 1]]
```

> {21, 12, 5, 6, 97, 99, 29, 47, 96, 10, 26, 14, 56, 78, 46, 44, 70, 
>   92, 42, 24, 91, 16, 40, 87, 65, 48, 77, 79, 69, 31, 43, 85, 9, 3, 64,
>    35, 58, 7, 67, 81, 60, 20, 8, 19, 36, 11, 13, 86, 90, 62, 4, 53, 84,
>    51, 52, 22, 72, 88, 2, 95, 30, 18, 1, 61, 93, 45, 80, 34, 39, 37,
>   25,  50, 75, 68, 71, 27, 32, 49, 82, 73, 57, 100, 28, 17, 76, 55, 59,
>   15,  74, 54, 41, 94, 89, 66, 23, 98, 63, 38, 33, 83}

```
r2 = Reap[
   BreadthFirstScan[g, roots[[1]], {"PrevisitVertex" -> Sow}]][[2, 1]]

r3 = VertexComponent[g, 21]

r1 == r2 == r3
```

> True

Comment: runs like a charm - thank you very much!

Comment: +1 p.s. That's quite nice form of your roots function: `Pick[VertexList[#], VertexDegree[#], 1]&`

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `DepthFirstScan`, as in:

```
vlist = {}
DepthFirstScan[tree, 1, {"PrevisitVertex"-> (vlist = Append[vlist, #]&)}]
```

**UPDATE**

As Mark points out, that does not work, what does work (almost) is

```
Reap[DepthFirstScan[tree2, 1, {"PrevisitVertex" -> Sow}]]
```

However, this will give non-leaf vertices multiple times. What do you actually want it to do?

Comment: I get a sequence of errors of the form:
Function::flpar: Parameter specification Append[vlist,#1] in Function[Append[vlist,#1],1] should be a symbol or a list of symbols. >> 
I guess this can be fixed using `SetDelayed` rather than `Set`.

Comment: @MarkMcClure See the edit for a more elegant solution, sorry.

Comment: I'e added some clarification - I'm interested in some particular trees, with only one branch (in other words where such ordering occurs).